# AttributeError: module 'pytorch_lightning.utilities.distributed' has no attribute 'log'

Tags: python, pytorch-lightning

I am working with visual studio code in a personal / local enviornment for Visual Studio and Python:

```
c:\Users\Mister\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Forecasts\src\Test_Run.py
c:\Users\Mister\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\...
```

somehow when I try to run:

```
from neuralforecast.models import NBEATS
```

I get the errors:

> AttributeError: module 'pytorch_lightning.utilities.distributed' has
> no attribute 'log'

The error is in the ´utils.py`file in the neuralnetwork in this lines of code:

```
import logging
import pytorch_lightning as pl
pl.utilities.distributed.log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

I installed:

```
pytorch-lightning       1.6.5
neuralforecast          0.1.0
```

on `python 3.11.3`

Comment: According to [the document](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/latest/api/lightning.pytorch.utilities.distributed.html#module-lightning.pytorch.utilities.distributed), there is indeed no `log` method.

Comment: I installed the package with `pip install` so I wonder why this is int he code then

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are using `python=3.11`. You could try downgrading that version since `neuralforecast` is currently only supported for `python>=3.7,<=3.10`.

Recently, `torch` and `lightning` have released their new `2.0.0` version. So, installing from pip, be sure to install `torch<2.0.0` (`pip install neuralforecast "torch<2.0.0"`).

If you want to use the latest development version (compatible with `torch>=2.0.0`), you can install it using `git+https://github.com/nixtla/neuralforecast.git@main`. A new release will be available in pip soon.